# Windows 8 Sluggish performance on Virtual Disk

Tags: windows-8, performance

I made a virtual disk in Windows 7 and installed windows 8 on it as Windows 7 doesn't allow to make more than 4 partitions per hard disk. The installation was very slow however the videos on Youtube I saw, in them it installed very fast. (Those videos weren't fast forwarding the installation).

After installation Windows 8 performance was fine not like the performance I saw on youtube videos. After rebooting, Windows 8 became slow as heck. Boot time was longer than 1 min on a newly installed OS after that every thing was slow.

Why is that?

I have :

```
Core i7 2670qm

4GB ram
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a fixed VHD and not a VHD that can grow over the time. This improves performance a bit.